# What logic is used to order the sorted rows of a PowerBuilder DataWindow that contains duplicates in the sorted column?

Tags: powerbuilder

As is known, the data windows in PowerBuilder can be fashioned to sort the rows based on a columns value. This works fine if the values in that column are unique. However; I am working on a situation where those columns are not always unique and as a result, when the Sort() function is applied to the DataWindow, the duplicates are ordered in respect to the other rows but are not ordered in anyway themselves.

A better way to say this would be through a diagram.

Imagine the following data window:

Sort applied once
ID     DESCR     ACTIVE 
1      ABC       1 
2      BCD       0 
3      BCD       1 
4      CDE       1

Sort applied twice
ID     DESCR     ACTIVE 
1      ABC       1 
3      BCD       1 
2      BCD       0 
4      CDE       1

Sort applied thrice
ID     DESCR     ACTIVE 
1      ABC       1 
2      BCD       0 
3      BCD       1 
4      CDE       1

If I apply a ascending sort to the DESCR column, the two BCD rows will switch places. I am only applying the the sort on the DESCR column remember. It seems like the sort functionality randomly assigns a position to values that are duplicated. In my example, if I continually apply the sort function to that data window with an ascending sort on DESCR, the BCD rows will switch back and forth places.

For the question I have, does anyone know why it works this way? I have an idea of how to maybe solve it by applying a secondary sort to a hidden column that numbers sets of duplicate values. In my case, ID 1 would be assigned a 1. ID 2 would get a 1 and ID 3 would get a two. This way, the BCD values could be sorted on the DESCR, and then on this hidden column.

However; that is a lot more hassle to just keep the rows in the same order. Just polling the PowerBuilder developer community here on Stack to see if they've encountered this and if they've fixed it or know for sure that PB just randomly assigns an order to duplicate values in a sorted row.

Comment: It seems normal behavior to me for a sgbd that the order of the duplicates is undefined. If you want to keep the order of the duplicates, why don't you sort on both DESC and ID ? e.g : `SetSort('DESCR a, ID a')`

Comment: Agree with Seki. If you want the sequence of equal values to be consistent, you need to define that order. It's not unusual for sort algorithms to place equal keys in different orders depending on the initial state of the data.

Comment: That's what I figured would be the case. In the end, we are going to have the user set a secondary sort on the data using a unique identifier. I was hoping there was a mechanism in the sorting algorithm that would maintain positioning of equally valued items. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @nfootit : To be clear in the case you were wondering about the 'sgbd' (I forgot that this jargon term is french) :  I meant 'DBMS' :-)

Comment: @Seki : Yes, I had to google it. After I saw mostly French results, and in combination with your profile, I was able to figure it out. :)

Comment: @nfootit: Thanks for adding the data, and a way to visualize your question.  I don't think the question would have made sense otherwise.  I agree with the consensus here that the secondary sort is not consistent unless it is explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the column ACTIVE to the sort criteria (even if you don't really need it to be sorted - it will not harm!), and the problem is solved!